# Developing for TI's CC430F5137 MCU

Tags: microcontroller, rf, msp430, programmer, jtag

I'm developing an embedded systems project (I'm quite new to the area) and I have determined that I want to use the [CC430F5137](http://www.ti.com/product/cc430f5137), my problem is: How can I develop for it?

From cross-compilation, to driver software, to: USB -> JTAG, JTAG -> Programmer and programmer to the MCU itself. Are these the normal steps in the process?

Can a CC430F5137 be programmed with a generic MSP430 programmer? I realize this is more than one question, but mainly I would like to know how I can develop for TI's CC430F5137 MCU.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing Spy Bi-Wire next to JTAG on the datasheet. This 2-wire (plus power and ground) programming/debugging interface means you don't even need a JTAG programmer : the low cost [Launchpad](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_%28MSP-EXP430G2%29)  or [EZ340 boards](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-f2013) or [EZ-430 RF2500](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-rf2500t) can program the processor, for $5 or $10.

Not all MSP430 CPUs have Spy-Bi-Wire, but according to the datasheet you are lucky; this one does.

I use [MSP-gcc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/) (actually [MSP430-Ada](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msp430ada/) as an alternative to c) for program development, and [mspdebug](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mspdebug/) with either of the above programmers.

Comment: Thank you, I found Launchpad just before I read this, I'm buying it because it's so cheap and great for prototyping. Can I use the programmers you mentioned to program more than one CC430F5137? Is the MCU detachable, so I can flash the my binary to any number of MCU's?

Comment: The MCU on the Launchpad is socketed but it's only in a 20-pin socket. The way you use the Launchpad with your own CPU (which is in a 48-pin package) is via a 4-wire cable (or 4 separate wires!) to a connector (or pins!) on your own PCB.

Answer (score 1):

To get started, you probably will want a development board, like [CC430F5137 Wireless Development Tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/em430f5137rf900), which has a JTAG interface. Studying its schematic and the datasheet, you should be able to design your own board.

Then you can use a programmer like the [MSP-FET430UIF](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-fet430uif) (from what I read in its datasheet, the CC430F5137 is supported), using a development environment like Code Composer.